# Cordova 4.3 creates project MainActivity-CordovaLib

Tags: eclipse, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

In previous versions, the command:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Had created the Hello project and the **Hello**-CordovaLib project.
Currently, at which realized from the 4.3 version, the Hello and **MainActivity**-CordovaLib projects are created.

The questions is:

1. Is possible to create *-CordovaLib with the project name replacing the * ?
2. Is safe to rename the project?